# ReadAsAsync<> in PCL Repack of System.Net.Http.Formatting library

Tags: c#, rest, json.net, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting the following error when trying to envoke the ReadAsAsync<> extension method in the Bitrium.Http.Extensions repack of System.Net.Http.Formatting.

> Method 'SerializeToStreamAsync' in type
>   'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' from assembly
>   'Bitrium.Http.Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=43390f7aed073600' does not have an implementation.

I have something similar to the following code in a PCL project which I am testing via a simple unit test. I am not implementing the await pattern, but I do not believe it is related here.

```
public class RestApi()
{
    public void Get()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        response = client.GetAsync("http://someUrl.com").Result;
        var modelList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Model>>().Result; // I get the exception here
     }
}
```

The call to the method:

```
var target = new RestApi();
target.Get();
```

Is there anything I can do about it at this point? I do not need the Async feature necessarily, so another implementation that still converted my response to my model would be fine as well.

Comment: Why are you using this PCL library instead of the WebAPI client?  What is the advantage of the Bitrium repackage?

Comment: There is a requirement that mobile applications connect directly to this larger backend library (PCL). This PCL will be shared by different applications (not just mobile). One of its functionalities is to connect to third party RESTful services. So I wanted to have these client calls to be in one shared namespace in this PCL.

The advantage of the Butrium repackage was to attempt to reuse the ReadAsAsync<T> extension method that is in System.Net.Http.Formatting library.

But I have since changed my mind and used a different approach with just Json.Net. I will post that soon.

Comment: I was really hoping the repackaging provided support for .net 4.  That would be valuable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using  Bitrium repackage in attempt to reuse the `ReadAsAsync<T>` extension method that is in System.Net.Http.Formatting, I opted for **Json.NET** instead. Therefore did not need to rely on the repackage, but rather just on the current standard implementations of the PCL build of the lib containing HttpClient (NuGet `<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.18" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />`).

```
var resultString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(resultString);
```

I found [this post](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/consuming-an-asp.net-web-api-using-httpclient.html) helful for the new Json.NET piece.